# How to prove that $\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, $(-x)*y$ = $x*(-y)* = -(x*y)$

Tags: proof-verification, real-numbers

I need to prove the above theorem from axioms of real numbers and previously proven theorem. 
Please please help me in that.

Comment: Please , Share some efforts in the question and try to include *Your work* too.

Comment: Which axioms do you think are relevant to proving this? Also it may be helpful to show the "previously proven theorem" for clarity

Answer (score 0):

Note first that $-x:=x\cdot-1$ is well-defined because the additive inverse $-1$ of $1$ satisfies$$x+x\cdot-1=x(1+-1)=x0=0,$$where the first $=$ uses distributivity. (I'm assuming you know the proof that $x0=0$, and throughout I won't mention where commutativity "doubles up" results, such as $x+-1\cdot x=0$.) Then$$-x\cdot y=(x\cdot-1)\cdot y=x\cdot(-1\cdot y)=x\cdot -y$$uses the associativity of $\cdot$, while$$-x\cdot y=(-1\cdot x)\cdot y=-1\cdot(x\cdot y)=-(xy)$$uses the same axiom.

Comment: What has to do -x = x.  -1 with x+ x.-1=0

Comment: @playstore Add the additive inverse of $x$ to both sides on the left.

Comment: On the left on which equation

Comment: @playstore The second one.